# MSDAIPP broken on Vista by Update, missing in Win7Beta

Tags: vb6, vbscript, ado, webdav

I have some code I am working on that worked just fine until I installed [Software Update for Web Folders (KB907306)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=17C36612-632E-4C04-9382-987622ED1D64&displaylang=en) into Vista SP1.  I'm using ADO with the MSDAIPP.DSO provider for acess to WebDAV and FPSE/WEC servers.

The same code works fine in a clean XP SP3 install, and worked before this update (but I will re-verify on a clean Vista install).

A short test case (a WSH script named IPPTest.wsf) is:

```
<job>
  <reference object="ADODB.Connection"/>
  <object id="cnIPP" progId="ADODB.Connection"/>
  <object id="rec" progId="ADODB.Record"/>
  <object id="stm" progId="ADODB.Stream"/>
  <script language="VBScript">
  Option Explicit
  Const WEBROOT = "https://your.DAC-or-WEC.server"
  Const USER = "youruser"
  Const PW = "yourpw"
  Const TEXTFILE = "yourtextfile.txt"

  cnIPP.Open "Provider=MSDAIPP.DSO;Prompt=NoPrompt;" _
           & "Connect Timeout=10;" _
           & "Data Source=" & WEBROOT, _
             USER, PW, adConnectUnspecified

  rec.Open TEXTFILE, cnIPP, adModeRead
  stm.Open rec, , adOpenStreamFromRecord
  stm.Type = adTypeText
  stm.Charset = "ascii"
  MsgBox stm.ReadText(adReadLine)

  stm.Close
  rec.Close
  cnIPP.Close
  </script>
</job>
```

When it fails I get the exception:

```
---------------------------
Windows Script Host
---------------------------
Script: C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\IPPTest.wsf
Line:   19
Char:   8
Error:  No such interface supported 
Code:   80004002
Source:     (null)
```

Worse yet, I cannot even get that far when I run the same script on Win7 Beta (I haven't installed the RC yet).  My Win7 Beta does not have MSDAIPP.DLL at all.

I've also tested using the funky sample [Microsoft Office Web Folder Client Sample (for MSDAIPP)](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=b1420922-c283-4f7f-9a8f-49e0e224805f&displaylang=en) written in VC++ 6.0 just to remove ADO from the picture.  The precompiled EXE will run and work (to some extent) on my messed up Vista SP1, and on the clean XP SP3, but not at all on a clean Windows 7 Beta ("can't create MSDAIPP.DSO" error).  I say "to some extent" because for some odd reason the Microsoft demo app displays blank file and folder names, though it can upload/download files and traverse directories just fine.

So it seems that ADO is looking for an interface that the MSDAIPP.DSO no longer exposes.

The "broken" MSDAIPP.DLL is version 12.0.4518.1014 and is located in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\Ole DB` as one would expect.  This Vista SP1 machine also has Office 2003 installed (and did prior to the "update").

So (finally) I have three questions:

- Is there a way to back this "Software
  Update" out?  It installs more than
  just the MSDAIPP.DLL, and as Microsoft
  says there is no uninstall for this
  "fix."
- Is there any workaround or subsequent fix that fixes the fix?
- What's the story on MSDAIPP and Win7?
  Is it present in Win7RC1?  Or will
  users need to install Office to
  obtain it (previously it was part of
  Windows beginning with Win2K)?

---

More information!

I found the following after a lengthy (lengthy) search:

[Webdav on IIS 6.0 Troubleshooting](http://blogs.iis.net/sakyad/archive/2008/11/19/webdav-on-iis-6-0-troubleshooting.aspx#comments)

> Note: The Web Extender Client (codename
>   Rosebud) is not shipped with Windows
>   Vista, and WebDAV functionality in Vista
>   is limited to the capabilities of the Web
>   Client service (the WebDAV redirector.)
>
> Applications written to leverage Rosebud and 
>   previously working without issue on Windows
>   XP machines may fail in Windows Vista.
>
> The additional WebDAV functionality of
>   the Web Extender Client had been
>   exposed  previously in Windows 2000
>   and Windows XP as the Web Folders
>   component, MSDAIPP,  and was accessed
>   in Windows 2000 via Windows Explorer
>   and in Windows XP via the Add  Network
>   Place Wizard. Web Folders have been
>   not been included in Windows Vista,
>   but  the Web Folders component is
>   still available as part of a Microsoft
>   Office  installation. Installing
>   Office 2007 on a Windows Vista client
>   experiencing Web  Extender
>   Client-dependent connectivity failure
>   resolves the issue.

At this point I suspect that by installing Office 2003 I added what was formerly a fundamental Windows capability to Vista.  Subsequently installing the Software Update (which is Office 2007 oriented, though it was claimed to do no harm to previous Office installs) **broke** the functionality.  I do not recall this being in any Vista release notes.

Even if the Update can be made to work, this will be a huge headache for any programs that expect a working MSDAIPP to be present in Vista or Windows 7.

It looks like Microsoft just broke another spoke off VB6's wheel with this one by breaking MDAC/DAC.  That may be a premature assessment, and I'm awaiting any other suggestions or information.

I wonder how else Microsoft expects us to accomplish programmatic access via WebDAV and FPSE/WEC?  Is there a new API we should know about instead of using ADO with MSDAIPP (a.k.a. Rosebud)?

Comment: Loaded up a clean Vista SP1 VM and tested.  "No provider" error just as in Win7 Beta.  This answers the out of box support question I guess.  So the question probably becomes how to fix the Office 2007 Software Update version or what to substitute for MSDAIP instead.

Comment: One more tidbit here:  Using the Software Update version of MSDAIPP from 2008 *does* work to a limited extent.  You can use ADO to pull directory listings and even to create directories, delete files and directories, and create (empty) files.  What you can't seemingly do is open a Stream to a file.

Comment: I wish more questions were as detailed as this. Bravo. Unfortunately it's outside my circle of knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for reading though.  I did find that you can extract the RosebudMUI.msi from the .EXE of the Update, and even right-click and choose Uninstall.  Sadly, on Vista at least (system file protection?) the version 12 MSDAIPP remains in place.  Removing it may require manual unregistration and removal of the components.  Even then I have no alternative once done (maybe reinstall office 2003?).  Sadly I was hoping this was reliable as a system component my programs could use.  That or locate a redist package for version 11 or earlier.

Comment: Oh, and the KB907306 version of MSDAIPP.DSO **can** be used in a degenerate manner to open a Stream to a Source string of the form "URL=..." but any supplied user credentials are ignored (a dialog requesting user/pw pops up and can't be suppressed). *stm.Open "URL=" & WEBROOT & "/" & TEXTFILE, adModeRead, adOpenStreamUnspecified, USER, PW*

Comment: Comment here to avoid nudging **John Saunders** below at this time:  The KB956790 hotfix didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it's time to ask Microsoft about this.

---

**UPDATE:**
I'll see if I can find someone to get you a more definitive answer. If you don't hear back from me or someone else, "ping" me by adding another comment to this answer, in about a week.

Comment: Any idea where to begin?  I didn't see anything on the download page or in the KB article about requesting support for problems with this Update.  Maybe one could stretch a point since they claimed it addresses "security" and get a free incident report?  Then again it isn't a mandatory security patch or something.  I do see that this Update was released twice, though no idea what was wrong with the 1st one and trying to get to it redirects to the KB907306 download.  Hmm.

Comment: I'll start by requesting the hotfix from KB956790 and testing it.  While the description doesn't relate to my symptom directly it does provide a newer version of MSDAIPP.DLL and before escalating this further I should probably apply it.

Comment: I wondered if you have had any luck finding a solution or workaround for this?  I'm looking at 3rd party alternatives but so far I'm not finding anything elegant.  Most handle WebDAV to one degree or another, very few (none?) handle FPSE/WEC or whatever it is called in SharePoint now.

Comment: No, nothing yet. I've pinged my sources again. Ping me back in four days if you hear nothing.

Comment: It seems that well has run dry. I'm getting no help from that direction. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate you trying.  I'll have to cast about and see what else I can find in the way of an alternative.  Thanks!